# How to customize the caption as a figure number in the algorithm2e package

Tags: floats, captions, algorithm2e

I want to show the algorithm as a figure and cite that figure using the figure number anywhere in the page.

Below is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
Add on.\;
Rewrite off.\;
Redefine all.\;
\NoCaptionOfAlgo
\caption{\textbf{go to the room}}
\label{xyz}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you have to combine the `figure` and `algorithm` in a special way. Specifically, you have to put the `algorithm` *inside* the `figure` environment with a (non-floating) `[H]` specifier:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\NoCaptionOfAlgo

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    Add on.\;
    Rewrite off.\;
    Redefine all.\;
    \caption{\textbf{go to the room}}
  \end{algorithm}
  \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm assuming it would be possible to find a more suitable input (say, by automating the `[H]` specifier for `algorithm` and discerning between `\caption` for the `algorithm` and `figure` in a natural way, say `\algcaption` and `\figcaption`). However, the extent of you usage of this way is not made clear.